# Difference between u'string' and unicode(string)

Tags: python, unicode

This is a sample program i made:

```
>>> print u'\u1212'
ሒ
>>> print '\u1212'
\u1212
>>> print unicode('\u1212')
\u1212
```

why do i get `\u1212` instead of `ሒ` when i `print unicode('\u1212')`?

I'm making a program to store data and not print it, so how do i store `ሒ` instead of `\u1212`? Now obviously i can't do something like:

```
x = u''+unicode('\u1212')
```

interestingly even if i do that, here's what i get:

```
\u1212
```

another fact that i think is worth mentioning :

```
>>> u'\u1212' == unicode('\u1212')
False
```

What do i do to store `ሒ` or some other character like that instead of `\uxxxx`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'\u1212'` is an ASCII string with 6 characters: `\`, `u`, `1`, `2`, `1`, and `2`.

`unicode('\u1212')` is a Unicode string with 6 characters: `\`, `u`, `1`, `2`, `1`, and `2`

`u'\u1212'` is a Unicode string with one character: `ሒ`.

You should use Unicode strings all around, if that's what you want.

```
u'\u1212'
```

**If for some reason you need to convert `'\u1212'` to `u'\u1212'`, use**

```
'\u1212'.decode('unicode-escape')
```

(Note that in Python 3, strings are always Unicode.)

Comment: lets say, i have a str, '\u1212' then how do i convert it into unicode and store it?

Comment: i think you didn't get me, how do i convert '\u1212' to u'\u1212'?

i get false when i do this: u'\u1212' == unicode('\u1212')

Answer (score 1):

This is just a misunderstanding.

**This is a unicode string: `x = u'\u1212'`**

When you call `print x` it is will print its character (`ሒ`) as shown. If you just call x it will show the `repr`esntation of it:

```
u'\u1212'
```

All is well with the world.

**This is an ascii string: `y = "\u1212"`**

When you call `print y` it is will print its value (`\u1212`) as shown. If you just call x it will show the `repr`esntation of it:

```
'\\udfgdfg'
```

Notice the double slashes (`\\`) that indicate the slash is being escaped.

**So, lets look at the following function call: `print unicode('\u1212')`**

This is a function call, and we can replace the string with a variable, so we'll use the equivilent:

```
y = "\u1212"
print unicode(x)
```

But as in the second exacmple above, `y` is an ascii string that is being managed internally as '\udfgdfg', its not a unicode string at all. So the unicode representation of `'\\udfgdfg'` is exactly the same. Thus why its not behaving correctly.