# What's the difference of u'somestring' and unicode('somestring'), python 2.7

Tags: python, django, unicode, character-encoding, decoding

I was getting 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)' when I was concatenating python strings with Django model.CharField like this:

```
some_variable = unicode("jotain älähti") + self.some_charfield
```

After I switched to this:

```
some_variable = u"jotain älähti" + self.some_charfield
```

It didn't raise the error anymore. What is the difference between u and the unicode function in python? I'm using python 2.7.5 and Django 1.7.1 Why does it not raise the error anymore?

I'm not sure why it would have to decode in the first place. Isn't decoding the process of forming human-readable letters and words from bytes? I would understand decoding in this case if I needed to print it, but I never printed it. Could the decoding relate to somehow to the concatenation process? That in order for the program to concatenate, it needs to decode those both strings, and only after that it can make the concatenation, and then encode those to bytes? I had the coding method input like this in the beginning of the file: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: look at this answer:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510929/difference-between-ustring-and-unicodestring

Comment: You need to specify the encoding `unicode("jotain älähti",encoding="utf8")`, unicode is trying to decode as ascii.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi they are not the same. `unicode()` on its own takes an ASCII string and turns it into a unicode string (prefixed by `u`). This is why the OP was getting the error. In the 2nd example, OP added `u` before the string, making it a unicode literal, so there was no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u"ä"` is a Unicode text -- a sequence of Unicode codepoints. It may correspond to *different* byte sequences depending on  a character encoding:

```
>>> u"ä".encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa4'
>>> u"ä".encode('cp1252')
'\xe4'
>>> u"ä".encode('utf-16le')
'\xe4\x00'
```

The encoding declaration `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` specifies your *source code encoding*. It just makes sure that `b"ä"` bytestring literal is interpreted as `b'\xc3\xa4'` byte sequence.

The encoding of your source code has nothing to do with encodings that are used at runtime.

`unicode(bytestring)` is equivalent to `bytestring.decode('ascii')` here.

```
>>> b'\xc3\xa4'.decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Non-ascii literals characters (such as `b"ä"`) in a bytestring are deprecated in Python 3 and `unicode` type is called `str` there. You could add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top to interpret `"ä"` as a Unicode text on both Python 2 and 3.